# Logging for two different classes of the same interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a decorator Logging class for two classes of the same interface type, that would take the class and basically override its method step so it could print some extra things. I found this solution really bad because I am reimplementing things that are already implemented but I can't think of a better solution.

```
public class A :IA
{
    private int state = 0;
    public void printStep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A state: {0}", state);
    }

    public bool Step()
    {
        state++;
        return true;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Step();
        }
    }
}

public class B : IA
{
    private double state = 0.0;
    public void printStep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B state: {0}", state);
    }

    public bool Step()
    {
        state+= 0.1;
        return true;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            Step();
        }
    }
}

public interface IA
{
    void printStep();
    bool Step();
    void Run();
}

public class Logger
{
    private IA ia;
    public Logger(IA ia)
    {
        this.ia = ia;
    }

    public void Run() //Don't like this method especially because it shouldn't reimplement the run methods again
    {
        if (ia.GetType() == typeof(A))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                ia.printStep();
                ia.Step();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                ia.printStep();
                ia.Step();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT: what I would like to do is something like this

```
 public override bool Step()
 {
     var ret = base.Step();
     base.printStep();
     return ret;
 }
```

EDIT 2: I need to call the original Run method that would be calling an updated Step method with the added logging. Expected behavior from this simple example would be Logger of class A would print symbol A 5 times and Logger of class B would print symbol B 4 times.

EDIT 3: Why I am trying to do this kind of behavior? What I felt like is having two classes A and B that would be fully working without writing any information on its own. The Logger should take either of them and log every state that would usually change after each step. So I would get a perfect information. I could play with something like adding a boolean variable logging in the A and B classes but it just doesn't feel right.

```
public class A :IA
{
...
    public bool Step()
    {
        if (logging) printStep();
        state++;
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

EDIT 5: Changed the initial code so it makes more sense.
Use:

```
 var a = new A();
 a.Run();
 var b = new B();
 b.Run();
 var loggerA = new Logger(a);
 loggerA.Run();
 var loggerB = new Logger(b);
 loggerB.Run();
```

Expected output:

```
A state: 5
A state: 6
A state: 7
A state: 8
A state: 9
B state: 0.4
B state: 0.5
B state: 0.6
B state: 0.7
```

Comment: I feel like you've misunderstood the decorator pattern.  If you were following the decorator pattern, your logger would implement `1A`, then in its `Step` method, it would call `printStep` and then `this.ia.step()`.  You'd then use your `Logger` in place of instances of `A` and `B`.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense for the `IA` interface to both have the `Run` and the `Step` methods. Either `IA` is something that runs something (and performs steps under the hood), or `IA` is something that can perform steps, and `Run` is not part of the interface.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis but imagine the run classes being really complex methods and in the abstraction, it doesn't feel like the Logger should implement all the run Methods either.

Comment: But that's the thing with abstraction: `Run` is part of the role the interface plays in your application, `Step` is just the behavior of one or more `Run` implementations - such details should be in an abstract class if you have multiple implementations with that behavior (Niels Ladekarl's answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Logger class to implement the Decorator pattern, it must implement the same interface as the "decorated" classes (not just to encapsulate them as in your snippet).

By doing so you'll be able to achieve the desired behavior (similar to the one in your EDIT).

EDIT:
Assuming that this is the responsibility of the Logger to log something, IA doesn't have to contain the printStep() method.

Thus we have:

```
public interface IA
{
    bool Step();
}


public class A : IA
{
    public bool Step()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class B : IA
{
    public bool Step()
    {
        return true;
    }
}


public class Logger : IA
{
    private readonly IA _decorated;

    public Logger(IA decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public bool Step()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before Step...");
        _decorated.Step();
        Console.WriteLine("Step completed.");
    }
}
```

When instantiating the Logger you need to pass the object you want to decorate

```
IA notDecorated = new A();
IA decorated = new Logger(notDecorated);
```

Comment: could you provide a working example with a call of the Logger class?

Comment: please see in the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

If there's not a reason for other objects to be calling `Step()` directly it shouldn't be part of the interface. However, since I think you're making classes that may be mostly similar in shape but potentially very different in implementation, I don't think decorating these classes will get you what you want. I think it makes more sense to just add in logging where it's needed.

I included a toy example of what a modern logging framework (like [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog)) does for you. In my example, you can change whether or not you have logging by passing in a different logging implementation. In a real framework, you have different levels of logging that you can configure so that you can turn off logging completely or only log more important information.

```
public class A : IA
{
    private readonly ILog logger;

    public B(ILog logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private bool Step()
    {
        // some logic
        logger.Info("Something specific here.")
        // more logic
        return true;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            logger.Info("A");
            Step();
        }
    }
}

public class B : IA
{
    private readonly ILog logger;

    public B(ILog logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private bool Step()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            logger.Info("B");
            Step();
        }
    }
}

public interface IA
{
    void Run();
}

public interface ILog
{
    void Info(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILog
{
    public void Info(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class NoopLogger : ILog
{
    public void Info(string message)
    {

    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate your classes, you can pass in whatever logger you need.

```
var noopLogger = new NoopLogger();
var a = new A(noopLogger);
a.Run();
var b = new B(noopLogger);
b.Run();

var consoleLogger = new ConsoleLogger();
a = new A(consoleLogger);
a.Run();
b = new B(consoleLogger);
b.Run();
```

Comment: I am trying to log a state after each Step basically, so this doesn't really help.

Comment: If you're trying to insert new logic into an existing method, then I don't think wrapping the class with a decorator will help. A lot of how you would solve this depends on what your use case will actually be. If you're going to have arbitrary logging logic that is specific to each `IA`, then you could pass in a `Logger` into the constructor of `A` and `B` and during the `Run()` method they would call `logger.Log(...)` with the information that they want to log.

Comment: @Dracke I updated my answer to reflect your latest edit. Other comments/answers are suggesting you change how your classes are structured (which I agree with) but if that really doesn't fit your use case I think this could be more helpful. It may also help to give a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the shared functionality in A and B you can make an abstract class. Implement the shared functionality here and make the remaining methods abstract. If you strictly want to use the decorator pattern you could make an interface for the abstract class.

```
public class A : AbstractA 
{ 
    public override void printStep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A"); 
    }

    public override void Run() 
    { 
        base.Run();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        { 
            Step(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

public class B : AbstractA 
{ 
    public override void printStep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B"); 
    }

    public override void Run() 
    { 
        base.Run();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
        { 
            Step(); 
        }
    } 
} 

public abstract class AbstractA : IA
{ 
    public abstract void printStep(); 

    public virtual bool Step() 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
        printStep();
    }
} 


public interface IA 
{ 
    void printStep(); 
    bool Step(); 
    void Run(); 
}

public class Logger 
{ 
    private IA ia; 

    public Logger(IA ia) 
    { 
        this.ia = ia; 
    }

    void Run()
    {
        ia.Run();
    }
}
```